# Gateway VM: how to isolate several networks with common internet access

Tags: centos, firewalld

centos stream 9 firewalld 1.3.4:
virtual machine running as gateway:

```
enp0s1 pppoed device zone zone-external, 
br0 with enp0s7 internal network 192.168.8.0/23 zone zone-internal, 
enp0s8 guest-network 192.168.13.0/25 zone zone-guest, 
enp0s9 iot-network 192.168.14.0/25 zone zone-iot, 
enp0s10 test-network 10.4.4.0/25 zone zone-test, 
default zone public
```

How can I isolate different networks?